# Settings won't open on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: settings, system-settings

I've installed Ubuntu on my PC, but unfortunately when I click on "Settings" or type "sudo gnome-control-center" on the Terminal, a red dot appears on the left side of the settings icon, but it doesn't open. What can I do?

Comment: This answer might answer might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21862144/9324076

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237965/reporting-i-cant-open-settings-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1238021#1238021

Answer (score 2):

**1.** In the terminal, run the command:

```
sudo journalctl -f
```

Then launch the app from Activities.  Wait a minute without doing anything else, then close the app, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the `journalctl`.

**2.**  If that doesn't work, you might need to reinstall `gnome-control-center`.  Do so with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

And then run it from the terminal, `sudo gnome-control-center`, or launch it from Activities.