# How do I jump to specific settings via vanilla gnome-shell search?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, settings, search

I have installed vanilla GNOME Shell 3.36.3. I want to quickly jump to its specific settings yet when I start the search via super and I type to search, e.g. for "Display" all I see are software recommendations for programs having "display" in their name.

In order to go to the settings I have to type "Settings", hit enter, search or click for "Displays". That's very tedious.

Also I am very sure that gnome-shell used to function the way I am trying to use it in the past (maybe before 20.04?) as I very often have to change my sound and display settings due to my setup.

Comment: Related, may even be duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237965/reporting-i-cant-open-settings-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts