# I can't open settings after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: gnome

I tried following the advice in a previous answer, but could not reinstall gnome, and have listed the result of my effort.

```
jack@jack-ThinkCentre-M58p:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 12836 (unattended-upgr)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

cocomac, think I got it here---https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237965/reporting-i-cant-open-settings-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the pervious answer that you are referring to. Also, why are you trying to reinstall gnome?

Comment: Wait for unattended-upgrades to finish and try again.  Don't forget to run `sudo apt update` before doing anything else in `apt` and `apt-get`. You should also run `sudo apt upgrade` if there are any updates pending. You don't want to make the situation worse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)

Comment: waltinator suggested this Mar.17/14  to find the process that owns the lock.    "sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock"  This is result                                                             jack@jack-ThinkCentre-M58p:~$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
[sudo] password for jack: 
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/122/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

Comment: I ran "sudo apt update",ok, and "sudo apt upgrade", got this result

jack@jack-ThinkCentre-M58p:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for jack: 
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 14476 (unattended-upgr)...